# Text overlays over image using relative positioning

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, overlay

I want to position a text overlaying an image. Below is my currently used code:

```html
<td width="10%">
  <img src="tempballoon.png" alt="balloon" style="z-index: -1" />
  <div style="position:relative;left:30px;top:-75px;font-size: 32px;display: none">
    Test
  </div>
</td>
```

My problem is, although the text is properly overlayed, the "space" it consumes in the `<td>` is still there! When I tried to replace the 'top' position in the `<div>` with 'margin-top', it also affects the `<img>` and so the `<img>` goes past the border of the `<td>`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want `position: absolute` and the *container* to be `relative`:

```
<td width="10%" style="position: relative;">
    <img src="tempballoon.png" alt="balloon"  style="z-index: -1"/>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;font-size: 32px;display: none">
      Test
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: recommended creating a css stylesheet for more then one style property.

Comment: This answer is wrong, table elements cannot be positioned. Some browsers like Chrome apply it however it is not correct

Answer (score 2):

Why not set a div inside the TD set the image to the background of the div and the drop your text in the div?

```
<td width="10%">
 <div style="background: transparent url("tempballoon.png") no-repeat left top; font-size: 32px;width: 100%; height: height:[height of image]">
  Test
 </div>
</td>
```

Comment: This answer is not so versatile if the image being used is being upscaled.

Comment: @EnocNRoll no for a responsive website this is not the best choice.  However using a table in a responsive design would also not be the most versatile of choices so I figured I would give an option as both work for the OP's question.  Also of note the style z-index is superfluous because z-index only works on positioned elements.